# WARNING:tensorflow:Model failed to serialize as JSON. Ignoring... Layers with arguments in `__init__` must override `get_config`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, object-detection

I am trying to do mask rcnn with this link: https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN, but when I run the code, I get the following warnings and errors:

> WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Program
> Files\Anaconda3\envs\mask-rcnn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py:1635:
> calling BaseResourceVariable.**init** (from
> tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is
> deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instructions for
> updating: If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.

Also, it is showing

> WARNING:tensorflow:Model failed to serialize as JSON. Ignoring... Layers with arguments in `__init__` must override `get_config`.

The bounding box is not showing and shows the following information: `*** No instances to display ***`

I searched online and followed some answers like decreasing the detection threshold, but it did not work.

Comment: Same issue here.